# Exact routing matching routes created by resources in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What are the equivalent matching routes created from the using a resources route?

Please be exact.

For example what would the equivalent matches for:
`resources :users`

There should be 7 different match routes matching the 7 actions - index, new, create, edit, update, show, and delete.  Here is one of them:
Http Method: New (Get Action)
`match "users/new", :to => "users#new", :via => :get, :as => :new_user`

I have a few more but I would like to confirm what I have with the community.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you wanted to know what the code should be in the routing file so...

```
match "users/:id", :to => "users#show", :via => :get, :as => :user
match "users", :to => "users#index", :via => :get, :as => :users
match "users", :to => "users#create", :via => :post
match "users/:id/edit", :to => "users#edit", :via => :get, :as => :edit_user
match "users/:id", :to => "users#update", :via => [:put, :patch]
match "users/new", :to => "users#new", :via => :get, :as => :new_user
match "users/:id", :to => "users#destroy", :via => :delete
```

Comment: the show action is actually plural - match users/:id, the update line should be :via => :post, and the destroy line should be :to => "users#delete", :via => :delete.  Let me know if i am wrong but that is what I have in my code

Comment: You are right about the pluralization on show, I have edited the routes to reflect this. But the rest is right (look at @alokswain 's answer) the controller method is destroy and the edit http method is put

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it does give 7 different routes. From [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

```
resources :users
```

gives 7 different routes all of which would map to the Users controllers.

Those routes will be

```
GET     /photos             index       display a list of all photos
GET     /photos/new         new         return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos             create      create a new photo
GET     /photos/:id         show        display a specific photo
GET     /photos/:id/edit    edit        return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT     /photos/:id         update      update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/:id         destroy     delete a specific photo
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I already understand what the routes will be.  What I am interested in are the seven exact `match` routes created from using the resources keyword.

Comment: theres your answer below. sorry dint get what you asked for.